# pdf-lib textfield is being formatted wrong by fontkit

Tags: node.js, zapier

I am trying to set some textfields in a pdf which is using a custom font.

When I am setting the text of the text field and then embedding the custom form, some text is suddenly divided. The word "loftet" is suddenly "loft et". This dispappear if I click into the textfield after creating the pdf.
Here is the place where I load the fonts:

````
  const fonturl3 = "http://localhost/pdflib-invoice/SourceSansPro-LightItalic.ttf";
  const fontBytes3 = await fetch(fonturl3).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());
  pdfDoc.registerFontkit(fontkit);
  MessageFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(fontBytes3);
  
  let form = pdfDoc.getForm();
  const textField = form.createTextField('Message');
  let text = 'See here loftet, ser det ligesom nissen eller er det noget andet. \nDet her virker også. Det er jo vildt'
  textField.setText(text);
  textField.addToPage(page, {
    width: 500,
    height: 100,
    x: 55, 
    y: 400,
    borderWidth: 0
  })
  
  textField.enableRichFormatting();
  textField.updateAppearances(MessageFont);
  //textField.enableReadOnly();
  console.log(MessageFont.encodeText(text));

  // Serialize the PDFDocument to bytes (a Uint8Array)
  const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save()```

When I enableReadOnly, the textfield is locked as it should, but some words looks wrong. Is there someway to "emulate" a click (which is my only idea), or is there anything else I can do?
````

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I did see this note in the pdf-lib jsdocs

`Note that pdf-lib does not support reading or writing rich text fields. Nor do most PDF readers and writers. Rich text fields are based on XFA (XML Forms Architecture). Relatively few PDFs use rich text fields or XFA. Unlike PDF itself, XFA is not an ISO standard. XFA has been deprecated in PDF 2.0:`